# How to style el-button that has slot 'append' attribute

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, element-ui

I'm building web app with Nuxt and Element UI.
Now, I'm creating a searching like below.

https://gyazo.com/644132bd6ab45714668281eed296940f

I would like to make the button's background color red, however, somehow, style doesn't work for the search button. (There is a room around inside the button)

How can I fix it?

This is my code.

- SearchBox

```
<template>
  <div>
    <el-input type="text">
      <el-button slot="append" style="background-color: red;">Search</el-button>
    </el-input>
  </div>
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

Element UI buttons have `el-button` class, you can see that if you inspect that element.

It is not recommended to change background color of elements appended/prepended to `el-input`, because if you change the button's background color, it'll loose it's append "effect", so it'll just show you a button and input staying together. But, if you want to do so, in spite of that, refer to `el-button` class:

```css
.el-button {
    background: #f00;
}
```

P.S: You may need to wrap that button with any div, and refer to buton inside of that div